# Summation method for $1-3+9-27 + \dots $

Tags: divergent-series, summation-method

Is there a summation method to compute the series
$$1-3+9-27+\dots ? $$

We knew this is divergent in the usual sense, but there are summation methods for giving a sense to divergent series. For example: Cesaro summation, Abel summation, Euler summation, and so on. I am looking for a method like that.

I am thinking about the Euler transformation of this series, which gives the series
$$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\dots$$
But this series does not converge in the usual sense. Hence, it is not Euler summable.

Thank you!

Comment: You can make sense of this as a $3$-adic sum in which $4S=(1+3)S=1$

Comment: Thank you! This sounds interesting! Could you please give me more details or links? We are not familiar with $p$-adic summation.

Comment: In this case you count numbers as close if they differ by a large power of $3$. So the partial sums $1$ and $-2$ differ by $3$ but the partial sums $-2$ and $7$ are closer because they differ by $9$, which is a higher power of $3$. This feels very weird, but can be made rigorous, and indeed helps to encode important properties of the primes for applications. I found this as a possible first look http://www.madore.org/~david/math/padics.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Any [linear stable summation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Properties_of_summation_methods) under which $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-3)^n$ is summable must yield

   $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-3)^n = \frac{1}{4}. $$

   This is because the sum can be computed only by appealing to both linearity and stability: if $S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-3)^n$ is summable, then

   \begin{align*}
   S
   &= 1 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-3)^{n+1} \tag{stability} \\
   &= 1 + (-3)S \tag{linearity}
   \end{align*}

   and thus solving this equation for $S$ yields $S = \frac{1}{4}$. Unfortunately, it is not Abel summable.
2. On the other hand, it is Borel summable:

   $$
   \mathcal{B}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-3)^n
   = \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-3)^n}{n!}t^n \right) e^{-t} \, dt
   = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-4t} \, dt
   = \frac{1}{4}. $$
3. The answer may change if we replace the underlying field from $\mathbb{C}$ to other complete field $F$ of characteristic zero (which makes sense because $F$ contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Q}$). For instance, if we pick $F = \mathbb{Q}_3$ as the $3$-adic field, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-3)^n$ converges absolutely to $\frac{1}{4}$ under the $|\cdot|_3$-norm.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: +1 This is like my answer, but with much more substance backing it up.

Answer (score 1):

It's a geometric series. If you want to assign a finite, real number to characterise your series, then I believe that
$$
\frac{1}{1-(-3)}=\frac14
$$
is the most natural value to assign.

Comment: This looks like Abel summation, but the radius of convergence of the associated power series is $\frac{1}{3}$, and not $1$. So I think that I cannot apply Abel summation.

Comment: How Arthur's answer is 1/4?

Comment: @AkashRoy There are many methods to assign a value to a series. Conventional summation is one of them, but it often fails (like in this case, as your answer points out). Other methods exist which 1) succeed more often, and 2) agree with conventional summing for any series where both methods succeed. Thus it's natural to call these other methods "summations" as well. You might have heard that $1+2+3+4+\cdots "=" -\frac1{12}$. That's another instance of this phenomenon. In this case, generalization of summation of geometric series (which conventionally does not work for $|r|\geq 1$) gives $1/4$.

Comment: @AkashRoy As has been pointed out in the other answers, though, generalizing the summation of geometric series doesn't _quite_ live up to modern standards of rigour (at least when stated as simply as I have). So while my answer may be correct, I realize that I haven't really answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is divergent. Each term switches the sign and roughly triples the absolute value. This is not summable

Comment: We know this is divergent in the usual sense, but there are summation methods for giving a sense to divergent series. For example: Cesaro summation, Abel summation, Euler summation, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

By right it’s a divergent series but anyway, assign the series a value $S$ such that
$$S=1-3+9-27+\ldots$$

So,
$$S=1-3S$$

Hence,
$$S=\frac14$$

Comment: This is how Euler proceeded a long time ago. However, this is not a rigorous summation method in the modern sense.